# C++ compile-time state variables

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, compile-time

I'm interested in being able to do something like this:

```
 void ISR()
 {
    MEASURE_TIME(counters)
    do_something();
    MEASURE_TIME(counters)
    do_something_else();
    MEASURE_TIME(counters)
    do_another_thing();
    MEASURE_TIME(counters)
    do_one_last_thing();
    MEASURE_TIME(counters)
 }
```

which would somehow translate at compile time to this:

```
 void ISR()
 {
    counters[0] = measure_time();
    do_something();
    counters[1] = measure_time();
    do_something_else();
    counters[2] = measure_time();
    do_another_thing();
    counters[3] = measure_time();
    do_one_last_thing();
    counters[4] = measure_time();
 }
```

**Is there a way to do maintain and increment integer state with the preprocessor (seems unlikely) or templates?**

I know I can do this:

```
 void ISR()
 {
    int i = 0;
    counters[i++] = measure_time();
    do_something();
    counters[i++] = measure_time();
    do_something_else();
    counters[i++] = measure_time();
    do_another_thing();
    counters[i++] = measure_time();
    do_one_last_thing();
    counters[i++] = measure_time();
 }
```

but there's some additional value to having a compile-time index (which is difficult to explain here w/o getting into some proprietary details)

---

edit: this is on an embedded system, and `__COUNTER__` isn't available (I just tried it: `__COUNTER__` is not defined by my compiler or the preprocessor), and I'm not sure I could get Boost to work, at least not in its entirety.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132751 for preprocessor counters.

Comment: ...and in fact the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210155/44330 seems like it might work.

Answer (score 5):

`__COUNTER__` macro is your friend.

Comment: Keep in mind that Boost, for example, uses this macro, so your `__COUNTER__` may not start at 0 if you include certain headers.

Answer (score 2):

How about `counters.push_back(measure_time())` ?

Comment: No. I'm looking for compile-time solutions. (not to mention that STL is not available on my lowly embedded system; I'm just lucky I have C++ and templates)

Answer (score 2):

Get [boost](http://www.boost.org/) source code. See how [`BOOST_PP_COUNTER`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html) works (expect to get headache). Then replicate functionality in your code. Or simply use boost. Please note that `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` does **not** use `__COUNTER__`.