# Generate unique numbers at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, compile-time, side-effects

I want to generate unique numbers for each class in my header, primes in my case primes but let's say this should only be consecutive numbers i.e. 1,2,3,4,etc.

Of course I can hardcode these:

```
struct A { enum { ID = 1; }; };
struct B { enum { ID = 2; }; };
struct C { enum { ID = 3; }; };
struct D { enum { ID = 4; }; };
```

This is very error-prone since in reality the classes are not that small and if I add a new class in the middle I have to change all the following numbers if I don't want to completely loose the overview of the IDs.

I wish I could do the following:

```
struct A { enum { ID = get_next_int(); }; };
struct B { enum { ID = get_next_int(); }; };
struct C { enum { ID = get_next_int(); }; };
struct D { enum { ID = get_next_int(); }; };
```

But since constexpr functions calls can't have side effects afaik, this is impossible. I think using macros such a result is impossible too.

I would also be lucky with something like that:

```
struct A_id_holder : some_base_counter {};
struct A { enum { ID = A_id_holder::ID; }; };

struct B_id_holder : some_base_counter {};
struct B { enum { ID = B_id_holder::ID; }; };

struct C_id_holder : some_base_counter {};
struct C { enum { ID = C_id_holder::ID; }; };

struct D_id_holder : some_base_counter {};
struct D { enum { ID = D_id_holder::ID; }; };
```

But honestly, I have no idea how to implement that.

Can I achieve my goal and if yes, how?

Comment: What does this have to do with TMP? Is that an avenue you have explored, or are you just hoping a TMP wizard will come along with an answer out of the blue?

Comment: Yes, since this can't be done with macros, TMP is my last hope (or how to initialize an ID otherwise?). I would also be glad about other possibilities. I edited my post to be more general.

Comment: Possible dupe, or answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166337/does-c-support-compile-time-counters

Comment: For C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132751/how-can-i-generate-unique-values-in-the-c-preprocessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people do this with the `__COUNTER__` macro. But that's nonstandard, and there's only one for the whole program.

Here is a [C++ hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166337/does-c-support-compile-time-counters/6174263#6174263) I came up with using templates and overloading which is standard-compliant and supports multiple counters.

Answer (score 4):

I think that Boost preprocessor library can do that for you, maybe you should read that: [How can I generate unique values in the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132751/how-can-i-generate-unique-values-in-the-c-preprocessor)

There is an alternative depending on the compiler that you are using, gcc and msvc have a **___COUNTER___** macro that allows sequential number: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros

Answer (score 1):

If you use `gcc`, you can use [the `__COUNTER__` macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros).

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to hard-code a placeholder wherever you want a unique number, and then write a small utility to pre-process the files, perhaps keeping the last-used number in a file so it will persist across invocations.