# Static counter shared by all translation units

Tags: c++

I have a class template like so

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  Foo() : id_{generate_unique_id()} {}
  int id_;
};
```

Each instance of `Foo` must have a unique `id_`. I thought I could just use a static counter like so:

```
namespace details { // all this code is in a header file
inline int generate_unique_id() {
    static int counter = 0;
    return counter++;
}
}
```

Is this code correct? Am I guaranteed that all translation units will use the same static variable `counter`?

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: You're not using the `T` template parameter... Anyway, show a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique values at preprocessing across files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204389/how-to-get-unique-values-at-preprocessing-across-files)

Comment: This code is not thread safe.  After the "first" call to the function, two threads could enter, both see the variable is initialized to some value `N`, and then both functions will return `N` and who knows what happens to the static counter after that.

Comment: Thread safety is not an issue here.

Comment: @molbdnilo I considered doing that and calling it a day, but is the code I posted correct as it is?

Comment: @Lanting I try to avoid the preprocessor as much as possible.

Comment: Will static local variables be unique in inline functions?

Comment: They `generate_uniuqe_id` function in each of the translation units will coalesce into a single representation (i.e., there will only be one function address for the function).  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @eljay Thx specifically: "Function-local static objects in all function definitions are shared across all translation units (they all refer to the same object defined in one translation unit)." at your linked page.

Comment: @Eljay so I take it the code sample is correct then?

Comment: Yes, the code sample will work as you intend, with no undesirable side-effects.  I'm not aware of any non-compliant compilers on this matter, but... *knock on wood*.

Comment: @Eljay Actually, it does not quite work. In my code base, I have multiple dlls, and it seems that each dll gets its own counter. I think the only safe way forward is to define the function in one cpp, rather than have the definition in the header.

Comment: Ahh, I suspect DLLs do not support weak linkage.  If so, an unfortunate limitation.  Your solution sounds like the best way out of that pickle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing a global/static variable between a process and DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911994/sharing-a-global-static-variable-between-a-process-and-dll)