# Macro generating a valid identifier for template-class static instance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, macros

#### Background

I am tinkering with polymorphic serialization and deserialization in C++.
For that purpose I use a static map: `[type id-string] -> [type factory function]`.
Each type has to be registered in this map and I would like to do it at compile-time.

#### Approach

The naïve approach is:

```
/// Creates a concrete serializable type provided as a template parameter
template <typename T>
ISerializable* createSerializable() { return new T; }

/// Factory that registers a serializable type T
template <typename T>
struct SerializableFactory
{
    SerializableFactory(const char* type_name)
    {
        // registerType adds a type_name->factory_function entry to the map
        registerType(type_name, createSerializable<T>);
    }
};
```

Registering the types is done with the macro:

```
/// Macro that registers the type at compile-time using a static factory instance
#define REGISTER_TYPE(T)                                                   \
    static SerializableFactory<T> global_##T##Factory(#T);
```

For example `REGISTER_TYPE(ArbitraryClass)` will become:

```
static SerializableFactory<ArbitraryClass> 
    global_ArbitraryClassFactory("ArbitraryClass");
```

#### Problem

Unfortunately this will not work for `ArbitraryClass<int>` bacause `<`, `>` are not allowed to be used in identifier.

#### Question

Is there a good work-around to achieve registering arbitrary template type this way?

#### Alternatives

I considered the following alternatives (each has disadvantages):

- **Registering types run-time**: looks less elegant, requires more effort from the serialization user;
- **RTTI**: requires RTTI to be enabled, gives no guarantees that different types will have always different hashes/names (very unlikely of course, but still);
- **Asking the user to provide a type alias or alias name**: less elegant, more effort from the serialization user

**Update:**

- As @Svalorzen mentioned in his answer **anonymous namespace** can be used. Unfortunately, not being able to use the macro more than once in a translation unit is a disadvantage. E.g., for header-only types.

Comment: Have you considered using `__COUNTER__` macro instead of `T` to generate factory instance unique name? I know it's not in standard but definitely could do the trick here...

Comment: @W.F. no, I did not. Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, being non-standard is a disadvantage. If there are no side-effects, and it is supported by three major compilers, who knows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an *aha!* moment inspired by comment from @W.F. , @Svalorzen answer, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667564/1597714) answer. I believe it is quite a clever trick, which has none of alternative's disadvantages.

---

**Solution:** using an unnamed/anonymous namespace ***and*** adding `__LINE__` to the identifier should always give a unique identifier (unless the macro is used twice at the same line).

---

Here's how it looks:

```
#define MERGE(A, B) A##B
#define CREATE_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER(line) MERGE(unique_identifier_on_line_, line)
/// UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER generates identifiers like:
/// "unique_identifier_on_line_" + line_number
#define UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER CREATE_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER(__LINE__)
/// Macro that registers the type at compile-time using a static factory instance
#define REGISTER_TYPE(T)                                                   \
    namespace                                                              \
    {                                                                      \
    static SerializableFactory<T> UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER(#T);                   \
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution would be to always use the same name, but wrap it in an unnamed namespace. This would only allow you to register a single type per translation unit, but maybe that's good enough.

```
/// Macro that registers the type at compile-time using a static factory instance
#define REGISTER_TYPE(T)                                         \
    namespace {                                                  \
        static SerializableFactory<T> serial_global_factory(#T); \
    }
```

Otherwise, you could use the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macro tokens to create a unique name for your object - as long as you don't have to reference it anywhere else. There are others, a list can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry, I forgot to mention this alternative in my question. I will extend it. Yes, being not able to use the macro in the same translation unit can be quite a disadvantage for the user. E.g., header-only types.

Comment: @AMA Another option, which I've added to my answer and is similar to what W.F. said, is to use any preprocessor token which allows you to create an unique identifier.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was thinking about it. `__FILE__` macro is not very useful because it can contain arbitrary symbols. But then it hit me: unnamed namespace + `__LINE__` could do it. I've added my own answer. However if you feel that this is what you were suggesting, please extend your answer and I will happily accept it :)

Comment: @AMA Depends on what you need to do with that symbol. If it is just to add a hook to register a type, it does not matter what its name is. And in any case, if you need to use it again later, you could also add a pointer to it to your map to find it.

Comment: Yes, in my case I only need to register the type.

Comment: @AMA Then why do you care what its name is? =)

Comment: @AMA Ah I see what you mean. Arbitrary symbols may mean that it won't work as an identifier. Makes sense.

Comment: User may want to register two types in the same translation unit, so identifiers can't be the same (they should be unique). Nothing else I care about :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the type as a single name and use the name:

```
typedef ArbitraryClass<int> ArbitraryClass_int_;
REGISTER_TYPE(ArbitraryClass_int_);
```

You could also try to put it in a hash-map, where the key is the typename.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your suggestion is what I meant by *Asking the user to provide an alias name* in alternatives.

Comment: You'll also have problems, if you define them inside templates, causing the string will always be `"T"` for example. `typeid(T).name()` gets a real individual string, but shorten. You could expand this to the representation by library-functions. If you want to make it more dynamically, try to use a preprogressor, eg. written in python.